# Dieline of a Box

Tags: adobe-illustrator, packaging

How do i create a die line of a box for packaging? The measurements are 14 inches in length, 4 inches width and 8 inches height. The box needs to have a window for the product to be seen.

Comment: It's not that simple. There's different kind of boxes, different kind of way to open them, you need to know the thickness of the stock, where will the window be exactly, etc. You should contact the printer and ask for the dieline or at least provide an example. But anyway, packaging is a specialty, no one will write you a "how-to" in a simple way especially if you ask the question with only 2 lines of text as reference!

Comment: Hi VoiceBox, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. As go-me says, making dielines is a rather specific task, and we'd need a bit more info to accurately help you. Please [edit] your question with that info. Thanks! If you have any questions about GD.SE, have a look at our [help] or feel free to ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation reaches 20. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Contact the box manufacturer. They'll probably have a template and suggested guidelines for you.

Answer (score 2):

You draw it up in a vector-editing or CAD program, matching up where the steel die rules will appear w/ a custom colour (typically named “Die”).

As noted in the comments, you need to know the rules for placing these to match the equipment which will be used to cut out the die. If you work with a box manufacturer and have a die made, they'll work with you to get the design to meet your needs, then provide you with the die file, along with the die.

Then you can go to a flexography shop to have printing plates made, then you'll need to find a box manufacturer to print and cut out and fold and glue up the box.

Answer (score 1):

Creating die lines in what ever software first requires that you know the type of the box you want because we have various types of boxes with different locking styles and forms depending on the product you want to package.

From my own point of view you have to take all this stages into consideration even before bringing out the die lines to suit your packaging.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use one of the commercial products for this as well.
I'd recommend checking the following service that I helped built.

https://www.diecuttemplates.com/dielines

Comment: Hi and welcome to GD.SE. We ask that answers which include recommendations disclose affiliation (or non-affiliation) in order to avoid spam. Could you edit to add if you're affiliated to the resource you've posted?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I added the information that this is a product I helped built.  Hope this helps, please let me know if I should add more information. Cheers